# Bind nic to VM on VMware ESXi 5

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have physical server with 2 Broadcom NIC's.

First NIC connected to local network, via this connection we can:

1. Connect to ESXi hypervisor (hypervisor has local ip, e.g.
   192.168.1.5)
2. Connect to VM on this hypervisor (VM has network adapter, with
   local ip, e.g. 192.168.1.6)

Second NIC connected to "global" network. Via second link(and public IP), we can have access to VM from Internet.

How I may setup VM to use second NIC's connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an ESXi with two physical nics ?

If so, create one vswitch to bind to the first physical nic, and a second vswitch to bind to the other physical nic.

You can create a new vswitch from the ***Add Networking*** link, where you can add a new ***'Virtual Machine'***- At this point you should get the option of either creating a new vswitch, or binding to an existing one.

All you need then is to create port groups in each vswitch, and connect the VM's virtual interfaces to each of them.  Just make sure that your VM's eth0 is really connected to vswitch0, and eth1 to vswitch1. Sometimes the internal order gets flipped.

Comment: Yes, I have physical server with 2 nic's, and ESXi 5 installed.  In vSphere Client's "Configuration" tab, "Network" menu, I can create "VMKernel" or "VMNetwork". Where I can create **VSwitch**?

Comment: Adi, thnx for reply. I'll be able to apply you solution after 5 hours.

Comment: Adi, another question. Where I must set public IP? In Windows(VM), or in vmnic's settings?

Comment: The IP address should be set inside the VM's operating system.

Comment: big thanx, all works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: My network configuuration]

@Adi, is this configuration correct? **vmnic0** is **local** network interface, **vmnic1** is **global** network interface.

Comment: Yes, that should work. (assuming you're not using vlans)